# dialong ncurses calendar: how to remove week-number column

Tags: calendar, dialog, ncurses

When using the command:

```
$ dialog --calendar "Please choose a date:" 0 0
```

dialog produces a calendar using ncurses that looks like this one:
https://invisible-island.net/dialog/images/demo-calendar.png

Notice that the first column is the number of the week (July 5 is the 28th week of 1981).

How do I remove that first column, to give me a calendar without the number of the week? (I don't get any value from it, and it is occasionally confusing).

Comment: There's no option for this (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/a3435071088ecf7aed1ffe1626cfad51860b7665/calendar.c#L415)), and questions of this type are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your response -- I suppose there is no other source with greater authority on the subject. I posted my question in the "questions" forum. How can it be off-topic? Thank you again,